# Create an RSS feed from Existing RSS

Tags: php

Im using the Twitter API to read the Favorites RSS, it generates the following output:

http://vl3.co.uk/favs/getfavs.php

I'm not sure why this file seems to be incorrect, doesnt come up in my RSS reader or render correctly in the browser. Can anyone shed any light on this?

If the output is not valid RSS how can I make it so?

Secondly I'd like to cache the RSS feed to then use something like Magpie RSS Parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your URL seems to be served as text/html instead of application/rss+xml. Second, the XML content does not follow the RSS specification at all, so it's not going to work in a standard RSS reader.

RSS specs: http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html

Answer (score 2):

That's not RSS. You can't just create any arbitrary set of XML tags and hope that an RSS reader will understand it - RSS is [a standard](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html), with particular tags required.

Your best bet is to take an existing RSS feed and see how it's constructed. You can check a feed you've created against [the Feed Validator](http://feedvalidator.org/).